# Webjars not load correctly

Tags: javascript, java, spring-mvc, spring-security, webjars

I'm using SpringMVC 4.3.13 and Spring Security 4.2.4.
In the last days I add to my webapp the webjars dependency and all works fine if I already made login into the application.
The only problem that I have is in the login page where I can't use webjars because Spring Security cannot permit me to download the resources.
Here how I load the resources in the login page

```
<script src="/webjars/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Here the resources configuration in MVCConfiguration

```
 @Override
 public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
     registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations(/webjars/")
        .resourceChain(false)
        .addResolver(new WebJarsResourceResolver())
        .addResolver(new PathResourceResolver());
     registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("/css/");
     registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**").addResourceLocations("/js/");
     registry.addResourceHandler("/plugins/**").addResourceLocations(/plugins/");
     registry.addResourceHandler("/img/**").addResourceLocations("/img/");
     registry.addResourceHandler("/images/**").addResourceLocations(/images/");
     registry.addResourceHandler("/font/**").addResourceLocations("/font/");
     registry.addResourceHandler("/fonts/**").addResourceLocations("/fonts/");
     registry.addResourceHandler("/servlet/**").addResourceLocations("/servlet/");
     registry.addResourceHandler("/user/**").addResourceLocations("/user/");
     registry.addResourceHandler("/asset/**").addResourceLocations("/asset/");
     registry.addResourceHandler("/xslt/**").addResourceLocations("/xslt/");
     registry.addResourceHandler("/jsp/**").addResourceLocations("/jsp/");
     registry.addResourceHandler("/applets/**").addResourceLocations("/applets/");
     registry.addResourceHandler("/manager/**").addResourceLocations("/manager/");
     registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
 }
```

And finaly my WebSecurityConfig

```
 @Override
 public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
     web
        .ignoring()
        .antMatchers("/webjars/**");
 }

 @Override protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      LOGGER.info("Initialization HTTP configuration");
      http
          .csrf().disable()
          .addFilterBefore(authenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
          .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login", "/asset/**","/privileged/**").permitAll()
          .anyRequest().authenticated()
          .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login")
          .defaultSuccessUrl("/home")
          .successHandler(customAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
          .permitAll();
 }
```

Like you can see I already added the exception in the Security config.
I also try this config

```
.antMatchers("/login", "/asset/**","/privileged/**","/webjars/**").permitAll()
```

But without success someone have any idea.

**UPDATE**
The configuration of the resourceHandler and ResourceLocations are correct.
In fact after login webjars works correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not related to Spring Security.
The guilty is an old custom security layer that will be totally replaced by Spring security in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in your xml configuration file.

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/webjars/**" location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/"/>
```

or use JavaConfig

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
  }

}
```

Comment: already try but not work, also if I remove the explicit call to .resourceChain(false) the webjars not work